# Want to explore the world of app development

Tags: android, recommendation-engine

I have no idea about application development. Could anyone guide me to know from where should I start my journey? Suggestions regarding: * Any online course * Best Framework I could start with * Best language to work on * Place where I could find some cool app dev projects for beginners

PS - I am new to the field

Comment: dont ask questions like "what should i use"..you need to ask yourself what problem can i fix. for me, my very first application was a tool to remember birthdays, anniversaries, when to take meds, etc. yes, i could have used my calendar, but i wanted my own application. when you have that down, then you MUST THINK about the steps to make it happen. for me, i need to create buttons, a form, users, etc. then break that down... how do i create buttons... how do i have my db talk to my form. break it down to VERY basic steps.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct and that's the reason I asked this question. I just wanted to make sure that i don't start with a outdated language or a framework. Thanks for your advice. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/docs, this site is the everything. Google itself has given a startup project. If you want to learn from other(Audio-visual project) then https://app.pluralsight.com is on of the best options.

Answer (score 0):

This course by Google is neat.
https://developers.google.com/training/certification/associate-android-developer

Answer (score 0):

I can really recommend browsing through the course catalog of Udacity. https://www.udacity.com/

If you want to create Android apps Kotlin is a great language.